# Open a local file in codename one

Tags: codenameone

Say i have a .txt file i want to open and process in Codename One. I put it in the src directory. And there is no function to open it. i found this link

https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html

which states i should use this convoluted line to get an InputStream object

```
InputStream i = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/myFile");
```

but it just returns null.

this line

```
FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "fileName.txt";
```

seems to produce a path that phones use, so doesn't seem to work while developing from the IDE on a desktop.

Any one have any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `InputStream i = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/myFile.txt");`? If it's in your `src` directory that's the way to access the file. No other way is supported.

Comment: it just returns null.

Comment: Make sure you spelled it 100% right including case sensitive spelling. Make sure the file made it into the compiled jar file.